# PHP form sample produces only blank page

Tags: php, html, forms

Software/Applications: Notepad++ 6.5, Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

I copied a code online just to test on how forms work so I can map it on my real page.
But even I tried the online example code it still doesnt work in my end. Can pls someone tell me what's the reason behind this?

copypaste.php

```
<html><body>
<form action="DesignPageProcess.php" method="POST">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
</body></html>
```

DesignPageProcess.php

```
<html><body>
<?php

if ($_POST['submit'] == "submit") 
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];

   echo "asd".$name.;

   // - - - snip - - - 
}
?>
</body></html>
```

It returns a blank page.

Comment: Add PHP Error reporting

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Why are you using NotePad++ ? Consider using some much more intelligent software, like an IDE? NetBeans is screaming for this line `echo "asd".$name.;` You won't need a StackOverflow answer for syntax error, instead catch them by using proper software

Comment: During development set your `error_reporting` to 'E_ALL'. So that you can know what are the warnings or errors thrown in the page.

Comment: Why would you not use something simpler like NotePad++ and bloat yourself with a full IDE for PHP?

Comment: try to var_dump all the post values as the following : var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @icedwater Because then you get these kind of errors.

Comment: Which apparently isn't the problem (see below).

Comment: Just curious, how did you set up PHP on your webserver?

Comment: @icedwater i just installed the latest notepad++ version in the net then use it to create html and php files.. sorry if it doesnt answer your question but thats all I know about using notepad++

Comment: @bew Do you not have a web server running? PHP is a server side language. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: @CharliePrynn i think thats the answer sorry for being pretty stupid im just downloading it right now tnx!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra .

```
<html><body>
<?php

if($_POST['submit'] == "submit") 
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];

  echo "asd".$name; //Removed the extra . on this line

   // - - - snip - - - 
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: tnx for the reply i tried removing the '.' and also tried copying your code but it still returns a blank page. they are also in a same folder still no luck :(

Comment: Is this the full contents of your files?

Comment: @bew Works for me when fixing that error.

Comment: @Stijn I imagine he's not posted the entire file and theres more syntax errors.

Comment: @CharliePrynn it its the entire file as I told you I copied the entire code from the internet and try it

Comment: Then the PHP is not your problem. I've tested and it works. Try and use basic debugging. Just because you copied the code from the internet, doesn't mean it works.

Comment: @CharliePrynn ok tnx, sorry im just a newbie using it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];

  echo "asd".$name;

   // - - - snip - - - 
}
```